# Are questions specific to a university acceptable?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm interested in applying to ETHZ for my *master degree* in mathematics, and for this reason I would like to know some details on the program of the *bachelor degree* in mathematics held at this institution. Such details should be written in German on the website of ETHZ. However, I cannot read German at all. Would it be okay to ask here for those details? More in general, is it okay to ask for explanations on the curricula of specific universities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, questions about **specific** programs, courses, curricula, projects, and research topics are considered **off-topic** here, as they tend not to satisfy the "helpful to others" criterion for Stack Exchange questions.

Comment: However, I should add that it is very common that English-speaking students apply to ETHZ for their master degree: so the question would be helpful to someone else at least.

Comment: A quick web search turns up [this outline of the bachelor's program written in English](http://www.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor). However, just because English-speaking students might be interested, the idea of not talking about specific programs and topics is an important one. We want to keep the discussion at a higher level than having tons of questions about individual departments, classes, and programs.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for the link. I had found that too, but it seems not specific enough (I mean, at least at my university there is a *far more* specific description of the courses).